# Google play console new App content Ads section disabled even after completing all sections

Tags: google-play-console

I have created a new play console account but after filling out the required section the **Ads** section in **App Content** is still greyed out. Play console doesn't have this menu in the older accounts. [Screenshot of my account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEsal.png)

[image]

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: I faced the same problem earlier today, I switch the web browser to Safari and it works

Comment: Faced the same problem. Changed to Safari as well. It worked. They should fix it for Chrome though!

Answer (score 3):

If you have an ad blocker on your browser, turn it off, and reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your browser.